# Changing background color of an element in AngularJS based on info read from Json

Tags: css, angularjs, filter, directive

So basically I have a calendar. In slots are simple time strings taken from an array. On a slot click i take the time value and the class "sunday" for example that is connected to the element and add these to a Date obj to get the overall concrete time of that slot. This than is converted to milliseconds and stored in a Json. I was trying to write a filter that would color the already chosen slots to green based on that Json. Trouble is that the filter doesn't really return CSS as well. Tried with a directive, but got a bit confused with the updates.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="x in slot60" data-ng-if="timeSlot==60">
  <td data-ng-class="[sunday]" data-ng-click="passSlot($event)">{{x|myFilter:sunday:this}}</td>
  <td data-ng-class="[monday]" data-ng-click="passSlot($event)">{{x|myFilter:monday:this}}</td>
  <td data-ng-class="[tuesday]" data-ng-click="passSlot($event)">{{x|myFilter:tuesday:this}}</td>
  <td data-ng-class="[wednesday]" data-ng-click="passSlot($event)">{{x|myFilter:wednesday:this}}</td>
  <td data-ng-class="[thursday]" data-ng-click="passSlot($event)">{{x|myFilter:thursday:this}}</td>
  <td data-ng-class="[friday]" data-ng-click="passSlot($event)">{{x|myFilter:friday:this}}</td>
  <td data-ng-class="[saturday]" data-ng-click="passSlot($event)">{{x|myFilter:saturday:this}}</td>
</tr>

{"timeSlot":"30","title":"Test","slots":["1439364600944","1439366400944","1439452800944"]}
```

I don't really have a working filter. I know this is not much, but I'd like to grasp the overall idea of how this can be done.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing, what do you mean with "slot"? 

Are these days of a week?

What are you trying to have in the final array?

Comment: It is just a simple time String taken from array. slot60 = ['09.00','09.30',....], In the end I am trying to establish a direct link between the selected values that are written in the Json under timeSlots and the CSS of each slot that is chosen, so that it is colored green in the Html as chosen.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function that tells wether the current slot is in the array or not, and just use an `ng-class` property to color the selected slots.

But for what you're doing, it would be pretty expensive in terms of computational power.

I suggest you change your approach.

The best way to do something like this would be to build a data structure that mimicks the available slots. Something like:

```
data: {
    <day1>: [<slot1>, <slot2>, ...],
    <day2>: [<slot1>, <slot2>, ...]
}
```

Then you could build the view based on the days and the slots with a series of ng-repeats, and each slot element could have title, status (free or occupied) or whatever, and ng-classes to display different styles based on the day, the status of the slot or whatever info you want.

You could then write a function that converts the data from this format to whatever format you need with your API when using remote calls.